# Chef Reconfigure Errors preventing successful run

Tags: chef

I am quite new to chef and is now trying to figure out why the following two errors are preventing me from a successful install.

```
Recipe: private-chef::redis_lb
  * template[/var/opt/opscode/redis_lb/etc/redis.conf] action create (up to date)
  * template[/etc/opscode/logrotate.d/redis_lb] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[set_lb_redis_values] action create
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'ruby_block[set_lb_redis_values]'
================================================================================


Redis::CannotConnectError
-------------------------
Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:16379 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

Also there is a second error:

```
Recipe: private-chef::partybus
  * ruby_block[migration-level file sanity check] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[migration-level file sanity check]'
================================================================================


RuntimeError
------------
ERROR:
The /var/opt/opscode/upgrades/migration-level file is missing or corrupt!  Please read http://docs.opscode.com/upgrade_server_ha_notes.html#pre-flight-check and correct this file before proceeding

* If this is a new installation:
  run: "cd /opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus ; /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/bundle exec bin/partybus init"
* If you have upgraded a previous installation:
  copy the /var/opt/opscode/upgrades/migration-level file from a not-yet-upgraded FrontEnd node

Error message No such file or directory - /var/opt/opscode/upgrades/migration-level
```

Please share your thoughts and ideas on these issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're trying to install the Enterprise Chef package. What you're seeing are two bugs we have when setting this up (Full disclosure, I'm an engineer with Chef).

The first in an error in the way we setup redis where we have a race condition between when redis starts and when the config is available. A second reconfigure fixes this issue I believe, as the config file is then available when redis tries to start.

The second issue is a bug with the Enterprise Chef upgrade process. The error actually gives you the work around. Assuming this is a new install, you need to run:

`cd /opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus ; /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/bundle exec bin/partybus init` and then run reconfigure again.

Given you're trying out Enterprise Chef, you can also contact support for help. Both of these issues should be resolved in the next version of the Chef server. My apologies that they've caused you issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a fresh install. I ran netstat -tulpn | grep 16379 and it came back with a pid. That turned out to be some sort of leftover from the previous installation. 
Killed that proc and ran chef-server-ctl restart / status and it was fine.